# Проведение Nunit теста

Tags: c#, nunit

Мне нужно провести тест метода на то что он выдаёт исключение.

Метод для теста

```
    public double AreaRectangle(double a, double b, double c)
    {
        if (a <= 0 || b <= 0 || c <= 0)
        {
            throw new Exception("Одна из сторон имеет отрицательное значение или равна нулю.");
        }
        else
        {
            if (a + b >= c || a + c >= b || b + c >= a)
            {
                double p = (a + b + c) / 2;
                return Math.Round(Math.Sqrt(p * (p - a) * (p - b) * (p - c)), 2);
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception("Одна сторона треугольника больше суммы двух других сторон. Такой треугольник не может существовать.");
            }
        }
    }
```

Тест

```
    [Test]
    public void AreaRectangle_ThreeSidesTriangle_ReturnedException()
    {
        // arrange
        var operationWithRentangle = new OperationsWithRectangle();

        // act
        var area = operationWithRentangle.AreaRectangle(-1, 8, 8);

        // assert
        Assert.That(() => area, Throws.Exception);
    }
```

Результат теста

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что я делаю не так?)

Comment: В act у вас должна быть подготовка делегата, а не вызов метода, который бросит исключение, а в assert передача этого делегата в метод Assert.Throws

Comment: https://github.com/AndrewNowosad/AreaCalculator/blob/master/AreaCalculator.Tests/TriangleAreaCalculatorTests.cs

Comment: @АндрейNOP В arrange подготовка делегата, в act вызов, в assert проверки что в ex лежит. Вроде так по идее если совсем аккуратно подходить.

Comment: @AK, не согласен, Assert на то и Assert, что он делает Assert :) если хотите проверить дополнительно текст сообщения, там есть перегрузка с параметром

Comment: @АндрейNOP Ну а как бы вы сделали сами? Я вот эту строку могу записать и в Arrange частично (подготовка делегата) и в Act несомненно и в Assert потому что есть указание что ловим: `var ex = Assert.Throws<ArgumentException>(() => operation.AreaRectangle(a, b, c));`

Comment: Не совсем по теме, но все же напутствие автору: бросать `Exception` в случае, когда вам известна причина возникновения ошибки (в вашем случае, `У прямоугольника не может быть сторон с отрицательными длинами`) - не самая хорошая идея. Для таких случаев, как минимум, существует стандартный `ArgumentException`, который означает то, что в метод передан неверный аргумент. А вообще, я предпочитаю для таких случаев заводить свой собственный`Exception` и называть его в соответствии со смыслом ошибки (например, здесь я бы его назвал назвал `InvalidRectangleSideException`).

Comment: @AK, а какая разница? На таком коротком тесте вообще без разницы. Я бы предпочел более короткий вариант, но без вреда читабельности. Примерно как у меня по ссылке выше

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Как-то так:

```
[Test]
public void AreaRectangle_ThreeSidesTriangle_ReturnedException()
{
    // Arrange
    double a = -1;
    double b = 8;
    double c = 8;
    var operation = new OperationsWithRectangle();

    // Act
    var ex = Assert.Throws<ArgumentException>(() => operation.AreaRectangle(a, b, c));

    // Assert
    StringAssert.Contains("Not a rectangle.", ex.Message);
}
```

Comment: Я сам уже сделал, просто надо было самому подумать, а не сразу на стек бежать) Но всё равно спасибо)